Issue in getting snowflake view definition
Is there a way to get view definitions from snowflake DB, I am trying the following options.
USE DADATABSE <<DBNAME>>
USE SCHEMA <<SCHEMANAME>>
SHOW VIEWS;

I need only "text" from show views output, please share your inputs
Thanks in advance.

Snowflake provides a GET_DDL function using which the DDL of database objects can be extracted.
Syntax
SELECT GET_DDL('VIEW', 'Fully_qualified_name_of_the_view');

Arguments
GET_DDL( '<object_type>' , '[.]<object_name>' [ , <use_fully_qualified_names_for_recreated_objects> ] )
The object_name specifies the name of the object for which DDL is required.
The namespace is the database and/or schema in which the object resides.
This is optional if the database and schema are in use in the current session in the worksheet.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl#syntax

You can use get_ddl to get the view definition
select get_ddl('view','<Dbname>.< SCHEMANAME>.<viewname>);

If you are looking for a text column from "show views" command then you can use result_scan function
USE DADATABSE <<DBNAME>>
USE SCHEMA <<SCHEMANAME>>
SHOW VIEWS;
SELECT "text" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));

Please review the below documentation for more information:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-views#usage-notes
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan
